# Extracting Zip Directory using PHP

Tags: php

The zip files in question are already located within a different location of the server. Using scandir of the directory they are located and removing the array values for '.' and '..' I have been  trying to get a method to work to unzip  the files & move them to a new folder on the server. I have been using the fairly common code of '-

```
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('$dir') === TRUE){
      $zip->extractTo('./unzipped/');
      $zip->close();
    echo "done";
    } else {
    echo "nope";
    }
```

Every time this is ran it just returns "nope". all the files already contain their extensions & the script has  777 permissions. is there anything I'm missing?

Edit - Sorry I should have mentioned the value of $dir is from the following:

```
$directory = '/home/karimo/public_html/test/Files/';
$files = scandir($directory );
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
foreach($files as $dir)
 {
```

It likely is a bad name choice but it 'works' for now. if I print $dir it returns the first file in the array as expected.

Comment: If `$zip->open()` fails, it returns an error code. What's the value of that code?

Comment: It returns the following: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class ZipArchive could not be converted to string"

Comment: I think that's a different problem. Try following @MrTechie's answer, but instead of just echoing a message, include the error code.

Comment: using $res=$zip->open($dir). $res returns the value '11'. I have tried MrTechie's method & it also returns the failed message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
    // assuming file.zip is in the same directory as the executing script.
    $file = 'file.zip';

    // get the absolute path to $file
    $path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($file);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
      // extract it to the path we determined above
      $zip->extractTo($path);
      $zip->close();
      echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
    } else {
      echo "Doh! I couldn't open $file";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I've merged this with the directory scan & appended the directory location to the value of $dir to give it  the full file path. I now get the "done" message however despite both script & directory being 777 I get permissions denied for  the extractTo command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like permissions are missing to access $dir . If it is a relative path you should check whether you expect the right base directory.
Aren't double quotes required to resolve variables inside strings in PHP? So that you'll need "$dir" instead of '$dir' ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. the value of $dir is the result of a "scandir" of which has returned all the files within the directory I intended to gather. I then used a foreach to loop through the files as the value "$dir" (likely a bad name but only I see the code).

Answer (score 0):

`if ($zip->open('$dir') === TRUE) ...`

In that line, you've put `$dir` in single quotes which would mean that it's looking for the files in '$dir' (literally that, not the value of the `$dir` variable), which will clearly always fail. You don't need to use any quotes there, but you will need to set the value of `$dir` further up.

Comment: I've tried removing quotes from around $dir & I've edited the original post (sorry didnt include where $dir comes from). $dir is previously set as a file from the directory.